# Github User Pages server DNS address could not be found

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I'm currently trying to get my github pages site up and running.

I actually went through with the process about a month ago without a hitch.

I left it alone between now and then, but when I went to start messing with it again today, I found that the site wasn't publishing for some reason. I just get a "server DNS address could not be found" when I try to navigate to it.

I tried deleting the repo and recreating it, but that doesn't seem to work.

And of course, I've insured that the repo name matches my username (case-sensitive).

Additionally, I contacted Github support and they said that they could load the page just fine.

Here's the [link](http://styx-.github.io/) if anyone would like to try it themselves.

EDIT: This is a "User" Page as opposed to a "Project" Page, so it shouldn't require a CNAME configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Reporitory url can be usefull. Current link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is working now. If you are still experiencing issues, please clarify a bit what it is you want to achieve.

In case you want to set up the site with a custom URL, you need to add a `CNAME` file to the repository. See the instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-pages-site-repository/